# Subsetting from an object created from a character string by the get() function

Tags: r, get, character, subset, assign

This is an example from the help page of the `assign` function:

```
> a <- 1:4
> assign("a[1]", 2)
> a[1] == 2          # FALSE
> get("a[1]") == 2   # TRUE
```

Instead of creating a whole new object `a[1]`, I wish I could overwrite the 1st member of the object `a`. I tried this:

```
> get("a")[1] <- 2
Error in get("a")[1] <- 2 : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

But it didn't work. I wish `get() <-` were a valid expression, but it's not. Is there any alternative for this?

What I'm trying to do is:

I have a lot of objects (data frames): `x11` `x12` `x13` `x21` `x22` `x23` `x31` ... (almost 20 of them). All of these objects contain 30 years of daily data. They were created using:

```
> for(i in c("x11", "x12", "x13", ...)) {
>   assign(i, read.csv())}
```

And now, I'm attempting to work with my data using a code like this:

```
> for(i in c("x11", "x12", "x13", ...)) {
>   for(j in 1:n) {
>     get(i)[j] <- "some.input"}}
```

And it gives me this message:

```
Error in get("x11")[] <- "some.input" : 
  target of assignment expands to non-language object
```

I hope, the problem I'm facing is understandable.

Comment: Why not just `a[1] <- 2`? What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But, this is not what I was looking for. I've updated the post for everyone's convenience.

Comment: Put these data sets into a list or into a single data frame with some index column. No need to use `assign` whatsoever. You may want to provide 2-3 small data sets and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with David's comments above, you can probably do this with a list of data frames. Your creation code would look like:

```
df_list <- lapply(c("x11", "x12", "x13", ...), function(i) {
   read.csv(...)
})
```

and your modification code:

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)) {
   for(j in 1:n) {
        df.list[[i]][j] <- "some.input"}}
```